# GROUP BY and SUM in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I need to calculate the revenues of three products in the year 2010.
This is my query, and I don't understand what's wrong
I'm sure that the joins are correct.

```
select p.product_de, c.year_de, sum(q.value) as sum_value
from products p
join quotas q
on p.product_id = q.product_id
join calendar_month c
on q.month_id = c.month_id
where p.product_de in('D - Product 7', 'D - Product 16', 'D - Product 1')
and c.year_de = '2010'
group by p.product_de, c.year_de, cus.customer_id
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns you SELECT, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. see what happens if you `group by p.product_de, c.year_de`.

Comment: What means that "something is wrong"? Just looking at some code you posted, it is difficult to guess. Why did you group by CUSTOMER_ID?

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by only queried columns. Also there isn't joined table cus

Try;

```
select p.product_de, c.year_de, sum(q.value) as sum_value
from products p
join quotas q
on p.product_id = q.product_id
join calendar_month c
on q.month_id = c.month_id
where p.product_de in('D - Product 7', 'D - Product 16', 'D - Product 1')
and c.year_de = '2010'
group by p.product_de, c.year_de;
```